Expo-Notifications giving firebase authentication error
I'm trying to implement push notifications using expo-notifications:
async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token;
  if (Devices.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    console.log(existingStatus);
    
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
      return;
    }
    try {
      token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
      console.log('Expo Push Token:', token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching push token:', error);
      alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
      return;
    }
    
  } else {
    alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
      name: 'default',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
    });
  }

  return token;
}

The status is getting logged in the console as 'granted', but the token is not getting generated and I'm getting this error :
Error fetching push token: [Error: Fetching the token failed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR]
All the authentication is working properly and the users are able to login. I don't get what the problem is. Could someone explain
I also tried native-notify as an alternative, but it worked only in expo go. I also tried changing the Devices to Constants, but it gave me an alert to use a physical device even though I was using one
